# How to get type from export?

Tags: typescript, types

If I was exporting

**baz.ts**

```
export default {
  foo: 5,
  bar: 'test'
}
```

then I was to do

**otherFile.ts**

```
import baz from './test.js'
```

How would I got about getting the type of baz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
type bazType = typeof baz;
```

Comment: ah some seconds faster than me nice answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

With `typeof baz`, you get the type of `baz`, like this:

```
type bazType = typeof baz;
```

Read more in [Type Queries and typeof in TypeScript](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/31/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript).

Comment: I approve of linking to documentation, but I think linking to the MDN Javascript `typeof` operator semantics may be misleading. Typescript will understand the type variable correctly but the javascript that actually executes will return `"object"` for `typeof baz;`